# Como contar o número de elementos TRUE dentro uma lista?

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como contar os elemento igual à TRUE dentro de uma lista lógica.

Tenho o seguinte objeto

```
> eigen
eigen() decomposition
$values
[1]  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  2.220446e-16  2.220446e-16 -3.469447e-17 -5.551115e-17

$vectors
              [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]         [,5]       [,6]
[1,]  0.000000e+00  0.5773503  0.8164966  0.0000000  0.000000000  0.0000000
[2,] -5.000000e-01 -0.2886751  0.2041241 -0.7830921 -0.005773308 -0.1083213
[3,]  5.000000e-01 -0.2886751  0.2041241 -0.0857628  0.548153314 -0.5631809
[4,] -1.110223e-16  0.5773503 -0.4082483 -0.3486646  0.587834659  0.1813378
[5,] -5.000000e-01 -0.2886751  0.2041241  0.4344274  0.593607966  0.2896591
[6,]  5.000000e-01 -0.2886751  0.2041241 -0.2629018  0.039681345  0.7445187
```

Gostaria de contar os elementos de eigen$values que são igual à 1, uma vez que eles representam o grau de liberdade de tratamento do delineamento estatístico.

Quando eu uso

```
eigen$values == 1
```

O que eu tenho de resposta é uma lista lógica

```
> eigen$values == 1
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Como contar a quantidade de elementos da lista que são iguais à TRUE?

Comment: `sum(eigen$values, na.rm = TRUE)`?

Comment: @neves Creio que é antes `sum(eigen$values == 1, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas é que como o AP colocou este último detalhe na última linha de código (`eigen$values == 1`), eu apenas coloquei o `eigen$values` para não replicar. Mas tens razão, pois nenhum objeto foi criado por ele, portanto necessário o `==1`. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Já respondido nos comentários; para explicar e ficar resposta registrada.

R codifica TRUE/FALSE como 1/0:

```
as.numeric(c(TRUE, FALSE))
#> [1] 1 0
```

Em operações numéricas, vetores lógicos são convertidos automaticamente:

```
TRUE + TRUE
#> [1] 2

log(TRUE)
#> [1] 0

c(TRUE, FALSE) + 3
#> [1] 4 3
```

Assim, para saber o número de elementos TRUE em um arranjo, pode usar `sum` diretamente:

```
vetor.logico <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)

sum(vetor.logico)
#> [1] 2
```

Para a quantidade de elementos FALSE, basta usar negação:

```
sum(!vetor.logico)
#> [1] 1
```

Assim como em qualquer vetor numérico, no caso de haver NAs, inclua a opção `na.rm = TRUE`:

```
sum(vetor.logico, na.rm = TRUE)
```